# Disabling two factor authentication to ios 10 is possible?

Tags: iphone, apple-id, ios, two-factor-authentication

I need to disable two factor authentication to iphone with ios 10+ version, is that possible? or is it possible by supervisor mode ?

Comment: what does disable to iPhone mean? Is this about bypassing activation lock where the locking AppleID has TFA enabled?

Comment: My teen safe app need icloud data access for parent mobile if user turned on TFA we can't get icloud data access so i need solution for disable TFA

Comment: @Subramani - you just need to make an application password. Go to appleid.apple.com, sign in, and crest an application password. This only appears once, so copy and paste it where you need. This will only work for one application.

Comment: Excellent explanation. I'll probably edit that in to the question - this is indeed a deep question and explores the boundaries of privacy and balance of privacy. You might not get a solution, but I look forward to learning how close you can get to one or if there is an entitlement you can request to get that iCloud access or engineer a shared container to allow it.