# Turning off the two factor authentication on an iphone 8 plus

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-id

How can I turn off the two factor authentication on an iphone 8 plus.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the phone, the phones don't do 2FA.  It has to do with your AppleID.  If you've turned it on more than two weeks ago, you can't turn it off.

Comment: I’ll try to link this to the question covering it. Please edit your question to clarify I I miss the mark or don’t answer your question. Just explain a little more if so.

Comment: Or are you more asking this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291471/disabling-two-factor-authentication-to-ios-10-is-possible